# Defining "inline" variables in C++0x

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, linkage

I'm developing a set of functions from an environment without not-full but high support for C++11 that are intented to be both callable with a multiple set of parameters but easy to pass to higher-level functions without having to force the user to force template parameter instantiations through casting, etc. So the most obvious solution to create these functions are by creating functors in the following way:

```
namespace mylib {

   struct functor_f
   {
      return_type_1 operator()(type1, type2) const
      { return something; }

      template<class Type3>
      return_type_2 operator()(type1, type2, Type3) const
      { return something2; }
   };

   static auto functor = functor_f();
}
```

The problem with that approach is that, `functor` will have a different address per translation unit, which could cause problems depending on how the user will treat the `functor`. If I remove `static`, then I have to define `functor` in a `.cpp` module, and thus adding an invisible level of indirection for the compiler from other translation units, which I guess can cause an important efficiency penalty, since these `functor`s are meant to be called thousands of times per algorithm (graph computations).

The most bizarre solution I can think of is to just, if I cannot guarantee these "object uniqueness", then I forbid its identification by forbiding taking the address of the object, assuming the user doesn't even know the existence of `std::address_of`, by something like:

```
namespace mylib {
   namespace _impl {
      template<class...>
      constexpr bool always_false() { return false; }
   }

   template<class T = void>
   struct non_addressable
   {
      // Or just make-it private, but I would prefer a cleaner
      // compile-time diagnostic.
      void operator&() const
      { static_assert(_impl::always_false<T>(), "Don't address me"); }
   };

   struct functor_f : non_addressable<>
   {
      return_type_1 operator()(type1, type2) const
      { return something; }

      template<class Type3>
      return_type_2 operator()(type1, type2, Type3) const
      { return something2; }
   };

   static auto functor = functor_f();
}
```

But I don't like it at all and I'm not fully sure about the side-effects of such a design.

There was any pre-C++14 idiom to achieve something like this? (simulating `inline` variables).

Comment: You're trying to counter a problem that is unlikely to be credible in practice.  There aren't too many practical uses for a functor with behaviour that depends on the address of the functor.   If a programmer goes out of their way to write such a functor, they'll probably go out of their way to obtain the address - which is easy enough, even if you have mangled `operator&()`.

Comment: @Peter I'm aware I'm crossing a border here, but what I'm trying to achieve here is object "uniqueness" without moving its definition to a translation unit on its own, but if I cannot achieve it, them I forbid the user the possibility of identifying the object (taking its address).

Comment: Why would defining the functor in a single translation unit cause any performance penalty as long as `functor`'s state is not used in the call operators?

Comment: @uneven_mark Some functors could have indeed state defining within its constructor, which would be invisible from other translation units. I've just put an example here.

Comment: I hate to say it, but what about a Meyers singleton?

Comment: If you want object uniqueness, make it a singleton of some form, and control its construction so it can't be instantiated more than once.   It then won't matter if the address is obtained, since the address will not change.

Comment: @NathanOliver The point is to allow users to pass "overloaded sets" in the simplest way as possible, so I wanted to avoid the user to call the constructor each time he wants to pass the functor, as you would do when passing a non-overloaded free function. Before making it a Mayers singleton I prefer to just remove the global, because we are in the same situation then.

Comment: @NathanOliver The uniqueness thing is because, when the "user" (which includes junior coworkers) sees it is a global variable, he could missuse it, although I don't have a clear picture of how could those missuses look like. I just prefer to avoid them somehow. The uniqueness thing (or the prohibition of identifying it) is then just a sort of counter-measure. Anyway, why do you "hate to say it"?

Comment: Why do you assume a static will produce an extra level of indirection? The linker's job is to replace place-holder addresses with true object addresses so that this is not necessary.

Comment: @MarkRansom I mean, not a static, but if I make it external, because the compiler cannot see how the constructor has been called in other modules so I assume there's a cut on optimization opportunities from the compiler.

Comment: The compiler will put guards around static initialization to make sure the static object is only constructed once.